# Hive set spark.sql.catalogImplementation to spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, jupyter

I'm trying to set spark.sql.catalogImplementation in hive. Already set spark.sql.catalogImplementation spark-defaults.conf  connecting through Jupyter notebook. When session is intilized spark.sql.catalogImplementation is set to in-memory from Jupyter. But when I access from the server it self from the pyspark shell spark.sql.catalogImplementation is set to hive. (check it from spark environment variables).

I can list all my databases when connecting from pyspark shell. But not from Jupyter.

I Use spark-magic to create spark sessions from Jupyter in my spark cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jupyter setup is done properly so  jupyter is not making use of existing spark-defaults.conf.

you can use findspark lib to use existing spark folder

```
import findspark
findspark.init('YOUR_SPARK_PATH')
```